# Generics and ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics

Given the following piece of code:

```
public class ClassCastTest {

    private static class GenericHolder<T> {
        private T object;

        public GenericHolder(Object object) {
            this.object = (T) object;
            System.out.println(getObject());
        }

        public T getObject() {
            return object;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericHolder<String> foo = new GenericHolder<>(3l);
        System.out.println(foo.getObject());
    }

}
```

Why does Java throw a ClassCastException in the second line of the main-method instead of the second line of the GenericHolder?

Comment: Why the cast anyway? Why not simply pass a T into the constructor, if that's what you expect? `public GenericHolder(T object) { this.object = object; }`

Comment: It's just an example ;) I don't need that code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the way generics are implemented in the language, your cast to `(T)` doesn't actually do anything.  It's only when you use a generic type in a way that actually gets out a concrete type -- here, `System.out.println` expects a `String` and it does the cast to get it -- that the runtime actually does any casting.

As far as the Java runtime is concerned, there's no difference between a `GenericHolder<String>` and a `GenericHolder<Integer>`; they both hold an `Object`.  Java just inserts casts anywhere you get a concrete type out of a generic type.

Research *[type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)* for more details.

Comment: But wouldn't the second line in the constructor do exactly the same? System.out.printLn still expects a String, doesnt it?

Comment: Yes, so it becomes `System.out.println((String) foo.getObject())`, it does the cast, and the cast fails.

Comment: but it only throws an exception in main, not in the constructor - so what I get from your answer is that it only tries to cast it to String in the main-method and ignores it in the constructor

Comment: Correct, because as far as the constructor is concerned a cast to `T` does nothing; `T` is basically always `Object`.

Comment: I've just noticed it's actually a `Long` not an `Integer`. I'm not sure if that was deliberate or not.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Louis' answer, it's useful to point out that casting to a `T` by writing `(T)` does "do something" in the case that `T` is bounded. For example, if you write

```
private static class GenericHolder<T extends CharSequence>
```

instead, then the line

```
this.object = (T) object;
```

*does* throw a `ClassCastException`, because you can't cast a `Long` to a `CharSequence` (note the question says `3l` not `31`). However it won't attempt to cast to a `String` at that point because the type `T` is not known at runtime.